# Join() in multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

According to join definition, the join thread executes till its execution is complete and is not prempted in the middle (correct me if i am wrong) .But in the following code: the join  thread t1 doesnt stop  the main thread to take the control in between the execution of t1. why so ?

```
public class JavaAtomic {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    ProcessingThread pt = new ProcessingThread();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(pt, "t1");
    t1.start();
    Thread t2 = new Thread(pt, "t2");
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    System.out.println("Processing count=" + pt.getCount());
}

}


  class ProcessingThread implements Runnable {
   private int count;


@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        processSomething(i);
        count++;
   System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+"---"+getCount())   ;
    }
}


public int getCount() {
    return this.count;
}


private void processSomething(int i) {
    // processing some job
    try {
        Thread.sleep(i * 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

output:

```
Thread[t1,5,main]---1
Thread[t2,5,main]---2
Thread[t1,5,main]---3
Thread[t2,5,main]---4
Thread[t1,5,main]---5
Thread[t2,5,main]---5
Thread[t2,5,main]---6
Thread[t1,5,main]---7
Processing count=7
```

Many Thanks
Jayendra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what is happening in your example:

- Main thread starts running, instantiates and kicks off `t1` and `t2`
- `t1` runs a little
- `t2` runs a little
- The main thread joins on `t1` and blocks until `t1` finishes
- `t1` and `t2` keep doing their thing.  We continue to see output from them.  Main thread is blocking.
- `t1` finishes and main thread unblocks
- Main thread joins on `t2`. However, it just so happens that in your particular output example, `t2` actually finished before `t1`, which is entirely possible under the randomness of the thread scheduler.  So, the main thread doesn't block on this second `join()` call because `t2` is already done.
- The main thread runs to completion and program exits.

---

### ADDITION

The above answer is unchanged.  However I noticed a thread safety issue in your code.  You have multiple threads incrementing the `count` variable in the shared `ProcessThread` instance by using the `++` operator. Please note that `++` is not atomic (see [this article](http://madbean.com/2003/mb2003-44/)), because it really consists of four operations: reading the current value of `count`, adding `1` to it, writing the new value back to `count`, and returning the value to the caller. In the gaps between those four operations, the thread scheduler could pre-empt the current thread and slip in another one carrying an outdated value read from `count`. Try increasing the number of threads and decreasing the time in your `sleep()` call and you will see the current count number appear inconsistent (same number may appear more than once, lower before higher, etc.) `count` becomes subject to race conditions between threads. The solution is to either enclose all reads/writes to `count` in `synchronized`, or to use a `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger`.

Comment: t2 runs a little->t1.join-> main thread waits until t1 finishes. but here t2 is called after t1 which is only possible when t2 called by its parent thread that is main thread. so how t1's execution is preempted which should ideally be completed first.

Comment: Once `t1` and `t2` are started, they run regardless of the status of their parent and nothing can stop them (other than the deprecated `stop()` method, which you should not use.) The thread scheduler handles pre-emption. The pre-emption of `t1` vs. `t2` has nothing to do with the status of their parent.  `join()` does not affect pre-emption; it does not give any priority to the thread being joined. All `t1.join()` says is: "block the current thread (main) until `t1` finishes." Since `t2` is running, that may take a little longer because the scheduler occasionally pre-empts `t1` to run `t2`.

Comment: you mean to say the switching between t1 and t2 is completely at the thread scheduler's disposal even if we specify t1 with join()..right?

Comment: @jayendrabhatt, The names 'thread' and 'join' come from a metaphor for a particular style of concurrent programming that was never as popular as its inventors had hoped (though, it may be coming back!).  "Join" is a really bad name if you aren't using that metaphor.  It should have been called "waitForThreadToFinish()" because that's all it does.

Answer (score 0):

Join stops the thread that calls join. It has no effect on the thread joined.

Comment: r/stops/blocks/ maybe

Comment: I think they have the same meaning here.

Comment: The word 'stop' is chosen a bit unlucky since a thread can also by really stopped and this functionality is deprecated. The thread that calls join blocks till the callee completes.

Answer (score 0):

when you call t1.join(), it won't have any effect on t1's execution. i.e It can't stop t1. t1.join() will wait for t1 to finish and then go forward in the execution.

Answer (score 0):

When main thread reaches the code `t1.join()` both t1 and t2 have been started and now main thread will wait for t1 to finish. But we can't predict the behaviour of running of t1 and t2, we can only assure that the last line of main function `System.out.println("Processing count=" + pt.getCount());` will execute only after thread t1 and t2 finish execution.